# Are my loops preventing me from getting the expected output?

Tags: java

My goal is to determine, for a pair of integers, whether the second integer  is a multiple of the first. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Multiples {

        public static void main(String [] args) {

            boolean run = true;

            while(run) {

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("Enter one number:");
                int num1 = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter a second number:");
                int num2 = input.nextInt();

            boolean result = isMultiple(num1, num2);

            if(result) {
                System.out.println(num2 + " is a multiple of " + num1);

            } else {
                System.out.println(num2 + " is not a multiple of " + num1);

            }

                System.out.print("Do you want to enter another pair(y/n)?");
                run = YesOrNo(input.next());
            }        
        }

            public static boolean YesOrNo(String a) {

                if(a.equals("y"))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }


            public static boolean isMultiple (int x , int y) {
                 if(y % x == 0)
                     return true;   
                 else
                     return false;

            }      
        }
```

This is my output:
[image]

This is the expected output:
[image]

The expected output is confusing me.

Comment: Btw, `isMultiple` could be reduced to `return (y % x = 0);`. The if statement is redundant.

Comment: Your output looks correct to me. Does it have to be exactly like that desired output?

Comment: @4castle yes unfortunately:( is it even possible?

Comment: @alyssaaa Everything is possible.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What's wrong with your output?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you for the encouragement haha:) I hope it's true in this case because I can't seem to get my code to match the expected output...

Comment: @alyssaaa Again, what's the problem, **specifically**?

Comment: In the expected output link, the user inputs "y" after being asked "Enter a second number:" and then the rest of the program just continues as "Do you want to enter another pair(y/n)?Enter one number:" I guess the "Enter one number:" is supposed to take in a pair of numbers and the "Enter a second number:" is supposed to continue/terminate the program when the user enters y/n.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the differences are noticeable when you look at my output and the expected output back and forth:) I just can't submit this due to the differences for which I don't know how to fix...

Comment: Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The expected output is "wrong". It asks for both numbers separately, but they're giving both the numbers when the first number is asked for, then giving a y/n when the second number  is asked for. Your output looks much more correct.

Comment: I agree haha therefore I have contacted both my professor and customer support to fix the issue :) Thank you for the help!